# Highlight the hyperlinks in google doc if link is present in middle Sentence /Line using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Okay So, I have a some complex google documents containing tables, and paragraphs and in the middle of these paragraph there are some hyperlinks which I want to find and highlight them I have tried many solution already provided on Stack Overflow but they are not exactly what I looking for those solution only works if doc contain direct URL instead of hyperlinks.

I have write some code which working pretty much fine. but the problem is if any hyperlink present in middle of any line or sentence so it will not targeting that hyperlink. only hyperlink which is single element or at starting of new line is getting target by this code.

here is demo file:- https://docs.google.com/document/d/16cbYg-g2pjpcBuUserhrCRfJw7VcHaXGvtmL0LxMzko/edit

code.gs

```
function highlightLink(){
  let highlightColor = {[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]: '#FFFF00'}
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let paraChild = body.getParagraphs();
  paraChild.forEach(ele=>{
    if(ele.getText()!= ""){
    let sentence = ele.getText();
    sentence.split(" ").map(item => {
      let word = body.findText(item.trim())
      let url = word.getElement().getLinkUrl();
      if(url!= null){
        word.getElement().setAttributes(highlightColor)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I have already tried the solution available on stack overflow but they not what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see `here is demo file:`.

Comment: @Tanaike sorry, please check now https://docs.google.com/document/d/16cbYg-g2pjpcBuUserhrCRfJw7VcHaXGvtmL0LxMzko/edit

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, it seems that the part of the text cannot be checked, and also, for example, when the same word is included in the paragraph, only 1st word is checked. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

How about the following modification when these points are reflected in your script?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
function highlightLink2() {
  // let highlightColor = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]: '#FFFF00' } // This is not used.
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let paraChild = body.getParagraphs();
  paraChild.forEach(ele => {
    if (ele.getText() != "") {
      let sentence = ele.getText();

      // --- I modified the below script.
      [...new Set(sentence.split(" ").map(e => e.trim()))].forEach(t => {
        let word = ele.findText(t);
        while (word) {
          let e = word.getElement();
          let start = word.getStartOffset();
          if (e.getLinkUrl(start)) {
            e.asText().setBackgroundColor(start, word.getEndOffsetInclusive(), '#FFFF00');
          }
          word = ele.findText(t, word);
        }
      });
      // ---

    }
  });
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

As another approach, the following modified script might be able to be used.

```js
function highlightLink3() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  const text = body.getText();
  const words = [...new Set(text.split(/[\n ]/g).map(e => e.trim()).filter(String))];
  words.forEach(t => {
    let word = body.findText(t);
    while (word) {
      const e = word.getElement();
      const start = word.getStartOffset();
      if (e.getLinkUrl(start)) {
        e.asText().setBackgroundColor(start, word.getEndOffsetInclusive(), '#FFFF00');
      }
      word = body.findText(t, word);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, your provided Document is used as a test. When you change the Document, this script might be required to be modified. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [setBackgroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setbackgroundcolorstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-color)
- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#findtextsearchpattern,-from)

Comment: this is really helpful and yeah now I got the real issue with script thanks for the help it's working with my demo doc. I hope it will perform same with the other complex docs

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh I noticed a modification point in my answer. So, I modified it. Please check it. And also, I added one more sample script. Also, please confirm it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help first script already worked great. but there is another issue which I trying to resolve actually suppose in doc I have already different color on some hyperlink but now its all yellow due to script how can get that same background or where i can store that data right. So, is it possible I can make custom find and go to button when I click next it send me on next hyperlink

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh About `but there is another issue which I trying to resolve actually suppose in doc I have already different color on some hyperlink but now its all yellow due to script how can get that same background or where i can store that data right. So, is it possible I can make custom find and go to button when I click next it send me on next hyperlink`, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: thank for guiding me please visit here I raise other issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082269/how-to-create-custom-button-for-find-and-go-to-next-hyperlink-in-google-doc-usin